# How to validate these special characters in AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-pattern

What is an appropriate ng-pattern for disallowing

```
\/:*?"<>|
```

I've tried so many different approaches.

Comment: Any string which contains these characters should be not allowed? or specifically the strings having this pattern?

Comment: Any string with even a single character of the above. For example 'abcd"ef'

Comment: I've finally came up with this ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9;`¬!£$%^&\(\)\-_+={}\[\]@#~,.' ]+$/" Is there any shorter version?

Comment: RegExp(/[\\*:*\?*"*<*>*(\|*)]/) Does this work in all cases?

Comment: How would it look like with ng-pattern. I'm not sure how to lay this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing it like so

```
$scope.fileNamePattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9;`¬!£$%^&()\-_+={}\[\]@#~,.' ]+$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this:

```
const re = new RegExp(/[\/*\\*:*\?*"*<*>*(\|*)]/);

console.log(re.test( 'abcd"ef')); //true
```

**Edit1:** Added validation for **' / '**

Comment: I think you are missing `/`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, think its fine now?